# Powershell $PSSscript root - how to add "\" to directory

Tags: powershell

I've ran into a problem in my powershell code:

I would like to take `$PSScriptRoot.ToString();` and then add it `\childfoldername` so it should look like this

> $PSScriptRoot = C:\New Folder\childfoldername

assuming that is $PSScriptRoot = C:\New Folder.

Tried `$PSScriptRoot.ToString() + "\" + foldername` but with no luck, still getting an error:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.

Comment: You don't need `ToString()` as `$PsScriptRoot` is already a string.  Also, I typically like to avoid string concatenation as it can get messy if there are lots of parts to join.  Interpolation will work nicely in this case:  `$newPath = "$PSScriptRoot\childfoldername"`.  If the suffix is in a variable, say, `$childFolder`, then you can use: `$newPath = "$PSScriptRoot\$childFolder"`

Comment: Better use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) for combining elements into a path or use .Net `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`

Comment: Based on the error you're trying to use this as a parameter. Your solution will work, you just need to put it in parentheses. A better solution however would be either `Join-Path` or `[System.IO.Path]::Join()`. Not sure if there are any differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) function.

```
$newPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "childpath"
```

Comment: Note that your answer addresses the title, however based on the error message in the body, not the concatenation causes the issue, see e.g. the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.

This error message implies that your problem isn't your *expression* per se (`$PSScriptRoot.ToString() + "\" + foldername`) but your attempt to pass it *as an argument* to a *command*, *without enclosing it in `(...)`*.

```bash
# !! WRONG - attempt to pass an expression as an argument as-is.
Get-Content $PSScriptRoot.ToString() + "\" + 'foldername'
```

```bash
# OK - enclosing the expression in (...) works as intended.
Get-Content ($PSScriptRoot.ToString() + "\" + 'foldername')
```

Aside from that, as noted:

- You don't need to call `.ToString()` on the [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot), because it already *is* a string.
- The preferable way to synthesize a path is to use the [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet:

  ```bash
  Get-Content (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'foldername')
  ```